# Using render in react router dom with a private route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Im trying to render two components within a private route using react router dom v4. This is possible using a normal Route but it does not seem to be the case when using a custom Route. I get the following error:
"Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
"

Custom route (Authenticated)

```
return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          this.currentUser()
            ? <Component currentUser={this.currentUser} {...props} />
            : <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: '/auth/login',
                  state: { from: props.location }
                }}
              />
        }
      />
    )
```

Then in my routes i want something like this

```
return (
      <div>
        <Switch location={isModal ? this.prevLocation : location}>
          <Authenticated path="/" exact component={Main} />
          <Route path="/auth/register" exact component={Register} />
          <Route path="/auth/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Authenticated
            path="/clients/:id/edit"
            render={(props) => ( // Not working as expected. Works fine using Route instead of Authenticated
              <div>
                <Main />   
                <ClientEdit />
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
        {isModal ?
          <Authenticated
            path='/clients/new'
            component={ClientNew}
          />
        : null}
        {isModal ?
          <Authenticated
            path='/clients/:id/edit'
            component={ClientEdit}
          />
        : null}
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your protectedRoute component, you are not receiving or utilizing `render` prop which you are sending in the line:

```
render={(props) => ( 
  <div>
    <Main />   
    <ClientEdit />
  </div>
)}
```

instead of using render send the component in `component` prop like :

```
component={(props) => ( 
  <div>
    <Main />   
    <ClientEdit />
  </div>
)}
```

Also check react router's docs to see when to use `component` prop and when to use `render` prop. It would be much better if you can change your `protectedRoute` to handle both.

Comment: Havent realized i could use component like that

Comment: Yeah since what you are passing in `component ` prop is actually an anonymous react component.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a little late, but for anyone still needing this, I found that this works for me.

```
export function PrivateRoute({ component: Component = null, render: Render = null, ...rest }) {
  const authService = new AuthService();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authService.isAuthenticated ? (
          Render ? (
            Render(props)
          ) : Component ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : null
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

And in my routes I use it like so:

```
<PrivateRoute
    path="/some-route/edit"
    render={props => <MyComponent {...props} isAwesome={true} />} />
```

Comment: I've found that when I declare the PrivateRoute with `render=`, then the browser momentarily displays the private component, and only then executes the Redirect.  However, when I declare the PrivateRoute with 'component=', then the browser immediately executes the redirect without displaying the private component.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a custom component returning :

```
return(
  <div>
   <Main />   
   <ClientEdit />
  </div>)
```

Then import it and use it in your authenticated component like this :

```
<Authenticated
   path="/clients/:id/edit"
   component={CustomComponent}
 />
```

Edit: you can also handle render prop in your Authenticated component if provided :

```
if (this.props.render && this.currentUser()) {
  return(
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={this.props.render}
    />
} else {
    return (
       <Route
         {...rest}
         render={props => this.currentUser() ?
            <Component currentUser={this.currentUser} {...props} /> : 
            <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: '/auth/login',
                  state: { from: props.location }
                }}
             />
          }
        />
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
const PeivateRoute = ({ component: component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
     <Route
        {...rest}
        render = {props => (false ? <component {...props}/> : <Redirect to="/" />)}
         />
);
```

};

export default PeivateRoute;

Comment: PrivateRoute.js