# React PrivateRoute declared with render prop displays private component before executing redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using an implementation of PrivateRoute referred to in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909865/using-render-in-react-router-dom-with-a-private-route) question.
The pertinent part of my implementation is as follows:

```
const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;
return <Route {...rest}
render={(props) => {
  if (authenticated) {
    if (this.props.render) {
      return this.props.render(props)
    }
    else {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
  } else {
    return <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />
  }
}} />
```

I've found that when I declare the PrivateRoute with `render=`, as shown here:

`<PrivateRoute path="/users" name="Users" render={props => <Users {...props} />} />`

then the browser momentarily displays the `Users` component, and only then executes the Redirect to the login url.

However, when I declare the PrivateRoute with `component=`, as shown here:

`<PrivateRoute path="/users" name="Users" component={Users} />`

then the browser immediately executes the redirect without displaying the private component at all, which is what I expect when using `render=`.

Why is the `Users` component displaying before the Redirect is executed when the `PrivateRoute` is declared with the `render=` property, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: how about ```return authenticated ? <Route {...rest}
  render={(props) => {
    if (this.props.render) {
      return this.props.render(props)
    }
    else {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
  }} /> : <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like even though you have overridden the render prop, it still is being executed when you pass it to Route using `{...rest}`. Destructuring it from props will give you the desired result

```
const { component: Component, render, ...rest } = this.props;

return <Route {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (authenticated) {
        if (render) {
          return render(props)
        }
        else {
          return <Component {...props} />
        }
      } else {
        return <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />
      }
    }} />
```